# Javascript variable name conflict

Tags: javascript

```js
var name = document.querySelectorAll('.info input[type=text]');
var name1 = document.querySelectorAll('.info input[type=text]');

console.log(name);
console.log(name1);
```

```html
            <div class='info'>
                <div>
                    <div><label id="dd">Name</label><input type='text'></div>
                    <div><label>Father Name</label><input type='text'></div>
                
                </div>
            </div>
```

javascript is producing different results for same code, only variable name is different. [this is the output produced on my device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKwvF.png)

Comment: `name` and `name1` variables are referencing the same dom elements. You could simply give both of your `input`'s a unique `id` and use that get their reference.

Comment: Something is odd here, your log of name1 shows 4 inputs?

Comment: You can add reference by adding separate id's for each input box. Now you are referencing same elements for 'name' and 'name1'

Answer (score 4):

There is a property called `name` on the `window` object that you are printing out:

```js
var name2 = document.querySelectorAll('.info input[type=text]');
var name1 = document.querySelectorAll('.info input[type=text]');

console.log(name === window.name);
console.log(name2);
console.log(name1);
```

```html
            <div class='info'>
                <div>
                    <div><label id="dd">Name</label><input type='text'></div>
                    <div><label>Father Name</label><input type='text'></div>
                
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem has to do with window.name : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name

As you're in the top scope, you are modifying window.name instead of creating a new var. window.name is being converted to a string, that's why it logs something different. You need to wrap that code in a function or use a different variable name.

Answer (score 1):

```
let [ name1, name2 ] = document.querySelectorAll('.info input[type=text]');

<div class='info'>
   <div>
     <div><label id="dd">Name</label><input type='text'></div>
     <div><label>Father Name</label><input type='text'></div>       
   /div>
</div>
```

Try using a variable instead of `name` since that might conflict with `window.name`, this will only conflict if you are using this variable in your root scope. Use a modular approach instead. To avoid errors like these.